# $on and $broadcast in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a footerController and codeScannerController with different views.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('footerController', ["$scope", function($scope) {}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('codeScannerController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
console.log("start");
$scope.startScanner = function(){...
```

When I click on a `<li>` in footer.html I should get this event in codeScannerController.

```
<li class="button" ng-click="startScanner()">3</li>
```

I think it can be realised with `$on` and `$broadcast`, but I don't know how and can't find examples anywhere.

Answer (score 647, accepted):

If you want to `$broadcast` use the `$rootScope`:

```
$scope.startScanner = function() {

    $rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started');
}
```

And then to receive, use the `$scope` of your controller:

```
$scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

If you want you can pass arguments when you `$broadcast`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started', { any: {} });
```

And then receive them:

```
$scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {

    var anyThing = args.any;
    // do what you want to do
});
```

Documentation for this inside the [Scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

Comment: You can name the event anything you like.

Comment: Make sure you are $scope.$apply(); your changes!

Comment: @Ismail Why... and where?

Comment: @Jaans Sometimes it didn't update my changed. I can't give an specific answer, I am new to angularjs. But I found out that it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Ismail OK thanks. I'm new too :-) I have since found out that it is best to wrap a `$broadcast()` call with a `$timeout()` call to "ensure that the broadcast is performed on the next available digest cycle" - what ever that really means. Something to do with the fact that Angular how angular does change/data tracking.

Comment: Are there any recommended practices for storing these strings somewhere rather than hardcoding the broadcast message?

Comment: @Rperryng that is a slippery slope. The reason you hard code these as literals is that it gives the developer team a visual record of the event which is occurring. Same reason we give variables logical names.

Comment: `$broadcast` or `$emit` could be used for this. `$rootScope.$emit()` may be a better option if only want to fire if on the $rootScope and want to prevent unnecessary traversing of all children in the scope hierarchy.

Comment: @th3uiguy Not really.  `$emit` travels *up* the scope hierarchy, while `$broadcast` travels *down* the scope hierarchy.  Since `$rootScope` is the top of the hierarchy, `$emit` would not work in this case.

Comment: @Ismail `$scope.$apply()` is only necessary when changing the model outside of the angular framework (like in a setTimeout, a dialog callback, or an ajax callback), in other words `$apply()` is already triggered after all code in `.$on()` is finished.

Comment: @DavinTryon see my jsfiddle of how `$emit()` could work: https://jsfiddle.net/th3uiguy/kjgj7Ldz/

Comment: is there any way that i can send data to this broadcast function from native side , lets say i have declared android broadcast , is there anyway that i can communicate with this ???

Comment: Are you sure that `$scope` can be here? I had to use `$rootScope.$on` to it work.

Answer (score 103):

First, a short description of [`$on()`, `$broadcast()` and `$emit()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on):

- `.$on(name, listener)` - Listens for a specific event by a given `name`
- `.$broadcast(name, args)` - Broadcast an event down through the `$scope` of all children
- `.$emit(name, args)` - Emit an event up the `$scope` hierarchy to all parents, including the `$rootScope`

Based on the following HTML (see [full example here](https://jsfiddle.net/th3uiguy/kjgj7Ldz/)):

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <button ng-click="broadcast()">Broadcast 1</button>
    <button ng-click="emit()">Emit 1</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <button ng-click="broadcast()">Broadcast 2</button>
    <button ng-click="emit()">Emit 2</button>
    <div ng-controller="Controller3">
        <button ng-click="broadcast()">Broadcast 3</button>
        <button ng-click="emit()">Emit 3</button>
        <br>
        <button ng-click="broadcastRoot()">Broadcast Root</button>
        <button ng-click="emitRoot()">Emit Root</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fired events will traverse the `$scopes` as follows:

- Broadcast 1 - Will only be seen by Controller 1 `$scope`
- Emit 1 - Will be seen by Controller 1 `$scope` then `$rootScope`
- Broadcast 2 - Will be seen by Controller 2 `$scope` then Controller 3 `$scope`
- Emit 2 - Will be seen by Controller 2 `$scope` then `$rootScope`
- Broadcast 3 - Will only be seen by Controller 3 `$scope`
- Emit 3 - Will be seen by Controller 3 `$scope`, Controller 2 `$scope` then `$rootScope`
- Broadcast Root - Will be seen by `$rootScope` and `$scope` of all the Controllers (1, 2 then 3)
- Emit Root - Will only be seen by `$rootScope`

JavaScript to trigger events (again, you can see a [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/th3uiguy/kjgj7Ldz/)):

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.broadcastAndEmit = function(){
        // This will be seen by Controller 1 $scope and all children $scopes 
        $scope.$broadcast('eventX', {data: '$scope.broadcast'});

        // Because this event is fired as an emit (goes up) on the $rootScope,
        // only the $rootScope will see it
        $rootScope.$emit('eventX', {data: '$rootScope.emit'});
    };
    $scope.emit = function(){
        // Controller 1 $scope, and all parent $scopes (including $rootScope) 
        // will see this event
        $scope.$emit('eventX', {data: '$scope.emit'});
    };

    $scope.$on('eventX', function(ev, args){
        console.log('eventX found on Controller1 $scope');
    });
    $rootScope.$on('eventX', function(ev, args){
        console.log('eventX found on $rootScope');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: how can I imagine the hierarchy of my app with the example that you have given. How can a controller be a parent or child.?? What I am trying to say is that I have series of state eg. LoginCtrl ->homeCrl -> notificationCtrl and so on.

Answer (score 27):

One thing you should know is $ prefix refers to an Angular Method, $$ prefixes refers to angular methods that you should avoid using.

below is an example template and its controllers, we'll explore how $broadcast/$on can help us achieve what we want.

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name"/> 
    <button ng-click="register()">Register </button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    Registered Name: <input ng-model="name"/> 
</div>
```

The controllers are

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.register = function(){

    }
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope){

});
```

My question to you is how do you pass the name to the second controller when a user clicks register?  You may come up with multiple solutions but the one we're going to use is using $broadcast and $on.

**$broadcast vs $emit**

Which should we use?  $broadcast will channel down to all the children dom elements and $emit will channel the opposite direction to all the ancestor dom elements.

The best way to avoid deciding between $emit or $broadcast is to channel from the $rootScope and use $broadcast to all its children.  Which makes our case much easier since our dom elements are siblings.

**Adding $rootScope and lets $broadcast**

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){
    $scope.register = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('BOOM!', $scope.name)
    }
});
```

Note we added $rootScope and now we're using $broadcast(broadcastName, arguments).  For broadcastName, we want to give it a unique name so we can catch that name in our secondCtrl.  I've chosen BOOM! just for fun.  The second arguments 'arguments' allows us to pass values to the listeners.

**Receiving our broadcast**

In our second controller, we need to set up code to listen to our broadcast

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    console.log(args);
    $scope.name = args; //now we've registered!
  })
});
```

It's really that simple. [Live Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YWKE0d6KzyHvIxK8os3V?p=preview)

**Other ways to achieve similar results**

Try to avoid using this suite of methods as it is neither efficient nor easy to maintain but it's a simple way to fix issues you might have.

You can usually do the same thing by using a service or by simplifying your controllers.  We won't discuss this in detail but I thought I'd just mention it for completeness.

Lastly, keep in mind a really useful broadcast to listen to is '$destroy' again you can see the $ means it's a method or object created by the vendor codes.  Anyways $destroy is broadcasted when a controller gets destroyed, you may want to listen to this to know when your controller is removed.

Comment: As a warning, try not to use too many broadcasts/emits in your app.  They can be extremely hard to manage especially in a big app since tracing the roots of these events is a very hard task.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Your broadcast in service

(function () { 
    angular.module('appModule').factory('AppService', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {

    function refreshData() {  
        $timeout(function() {         
            $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshData');
        }, 0, true);      
    }

    return {           
        RefreshData: refreshData
    };
}); }());

//Controller Implementation
 (function () {
    angular.module('appModule').controller('AppController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, AppService) {            

       //Removes Listeners before adding them 
       //This line will solve the problem for multiple broadcast call                             
       $scope.$$listeners['refreshData'] = [];

       $scope.$on('refreshData', function() {                                                    
          $scope.showData();             
       });

       $scope.onSaveDataComplete = function() { 
         AppService.RefreshData();
       };
    }); }());
```