# How to go back to the previous view with parameter in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In a view I have a link to choose a start location like below:

```html
<a href="#/location/start"><input type="text" ng-model="placeStart" placeholder="place to start"></a>
<input type="text" ng-model="weight" placeholder="goods weight">
```

and in the location page, I do choose a place, however, When I use $ionicHistory.goBack(), I could not pass the "place" back to the previous view. I also do not want to use state.go('previous view') to pass the "place", because in that way, I will lost the other input information in the previous view.

Comment: Please elaborate what you want.

Comment: Why are you put textbox in a href tag?

Comment: Wondering if any of the options in my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Here is :

```
$ionicHistory.backView().stateId;
```

don't ignore to include `$ionicHistory` on controller

Comment: Please explain more here

Answer (score 0):

There are three options which immediately come to mind. $rootScope, localStorage and using routing not goBack().

If you need the value from one view in another, and they're completely separate controllers etc then you need a way to pass them around.

You could create and then put the value into $rootScope.globals or similar.

You could store the value to localStorage before sending the user back.

You could redirect correctly to a route which allows the values to be included in the url and still show the provious page. For example the same route with and without values set, using - or 0 for not set depending on data type:

```
/an/example/route/-/-/
/an/example/route/0/0/
/an/example/route/123/456
```

**Update:**

There is actually a fourth way where you can send data between controllers using $broadcast and $on. The broadcast happens in the sending controller and the $on listens in the receiving controller(s) so you can send an update to values / an object etc. [$on and $broadcast in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular)

Comment: These are all true and viable suggestions. I added an answer with my preferred additional way of using a service object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation but if you don't care to preserve state after a page reload which `localStorage` would be good for, but rather have the state be remembered just when you're going back (and not necessarily when you later navigate forward back into the view again) then I do this: I make a separate service, just an object that sticks around in which I can inject anywhere and store some variables. In Angular 1 this would be a service object.

```
angular.module('foo').factory("placeHelper", [
    () => {
        let _place = null;

        class PlaceHelper {
            set place(place){
                _place = place;
            }

            get place(){
                return _place;
            }

            reset(){
                _place = null;
            }
        }

        let helper = new PlaceHelper();

        return helper;
    }
]);
```

Then in your controller that you're going back to, you inject placeHelper and ask it for the place and restore your state via `$scope.place = placeHelper.place` and when in the UI for that controller someone selects a place, you just store it in the service, `placeHelper.place = $scope.place`.

I would use localStorage within the service if I wanted to keep the state around after a page refresh.

I don't like polluting $rootScope because it's harder to keep track after you start to have more than a few unrelated methods in there and your properties need to have longer names (or get grouped in objects anyway). It's better for maintainability to encapsulate and separate concerns.

**Service variation:**
The service could be an object literal instead of a class and you could directly set the properties instead of using methods if you wanted it to be a bit more simple.

```
angular.module('foo').factory("placeHelper", [
    () => {
        let helper = {
            place: null,

            reset(){
                this.place = null;
            }
        };

        return helper;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same problem recently. I ended up deciding to use $ionicHistory.currentView() and $ionicHistory.backView() (see documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)). The former function returns an object associated to the current view, while the latter returns an object associated to the view you will go to after you call $ionicHistory.goBack().

Before calling $ionicHistory.goBack() on your location page you call $ionicHistory.backView() and define a new property to the returned object whose contents is the data you want to propagate to the other view.

On your other view, you change its '$ionicView.enter' event handler so it calls $ionicHistory.currentView(), which retrieves the object with the data you want.