# Match angularjs router pattern '?ref=value'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to match `example.com`/?ref=thing in my router.

Going off this example in the docs (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

```
url: "/contacts?myParam"
// will match to url of "/contacts?myParam=value"
```

I tried:

```
url: "/?ref"
```

But that doesn't work (ie. it does not direct me to that route)

I've also tried: `"/ref/:value"`, but no. Also: `/?` nope

All I can find in the docs is examples of routes that start with a base `files` or `user`.

Comment: are you getting some error?

Comment: @MukundGandlur, no, it just does not route it

Comment: Can you add a plunkr maybe? And see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473901/cant-edit-record-using-angular#comment60558386_36473901

Comment: If you could put some more code here. Like the Controller and state config, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you have this in your `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('listview', {
  url: '/listview?:id', // Output /listview?id=1234
  templateUrl: 'templates/listview.html',
  controller: 'listviewController'
});
```

Then you can just call the following function in one of your controllers and it will go to listview with a given id:

```
var url_id = 1234;
$state.go('listview', {id: url_id});
```

You can also do it like this:

```
.state('listview', {
  url: '/listview/:id', // Output /listview/1234
  templateUrl: 'templates/listview.html',
  controller: 'listviewController'
});
```

Also this will work:

```
.state('listview', {
  url: '/listview/?:id', // Output /listview/?id=1234
  templateUrl: 'templates/listview.html',
  controller: 'listviewController'
});
```

Hopefully this gives you the right direction.

Comment: Problem is, I have nothing before the `/?`, so no `/listview`

Comment: Well that's not how angular works I'm sorry. Can't you just add maybe one letter in the state url? For example `/a?:id`

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at AngularJS abstract states: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states