# How can get data to my page controller js from another controller js used in Master Page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Master Page Controllerjs:**

I am want to get following categoryId from event fired by $scope.braodcast  on my event(inner) page.

```
$scope.RedirectToEventPage = function (categoryId) {

    var url = window.location.host + '/events';
    if (categoryId == 'ALL') {
        $rootscope.$broadcast('CategoryId', 0);
    }
    else {
        $scope.$broadcast('CategoryId', categoryId);
    }
    window.location = '/events';

};
```

**Event Page Controllerjs:** 
$scope.on displaying 'undefined' with console.

```
 knrApp.controller("EventCtrl", function ($scope, eventFactory, $rootscope) {
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $rootscope.$on('CategoryId', function (event, data) {
        if (data == null || data === undefined || data == '') {
            $scope.categoryId = 0;
        }
        else {
            $scope.categoryId = data;
        }
    });

    // $scope.categoryId = 0;
    console.log($scope.categoryId);
    $scope.GetAllEventData($scope.categoryId);
});
}
```

Comment: check some great answer regarding $rootScope here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular