# ionic shopping cart in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, shopping-cart

I am making a online market app. There are i have shopping cart functionality but i do not know how i can realize it in ionic/angularjs. How i can do this or or is there a ready solution?
[image]

[image]

The problem is i have controllers for each page. But i need update badge value in each page.How i can update badge value when i clicking add to cart button in product controller?

Comment: What does the documentation of ionic say? Do you have any code you've been trying to work on so far?

Comment: I don't know of any ready-made solutions, but in order to "watch" events on another scope, you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Answer (score 1):

- you can fire an event in the controller, and catch it where the badge
  is.
- you can use the $rootScope service and save there the badge
  status
- you can implement your own service and save there the badge
  status