# Is Ionic Framework resolveLocalFileSystemURL Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise, ngcordova

I am calling a function from my AngularJS controller. When the function completes execution, I would like to print the result after the function call.

This code is inside the controller, which is called on-tap

```
  //count the number of files inside a directory
   var count = countDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory +'/Images/');
   console.log('Hello ');
   console.log('Count of directory '+count);
```

Here is the countDir function. This function finds the number of files in a directory and then returns the count back

```
function countDir(path){
          var count = 0;
          console.log('Counting the files inside '+path);
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
            function (fileSystem) {
              var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
              reader.readEntries(
                function (entries) {
                  var i;
                  for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++)  {    
                      console.log('File name ' + entries[i].name + ' added to count');
                       count++;   
                  }
                },
                function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              );
            }, function (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          );
  return count; 
}
```

The challenge that I am facing is that, my calling code first prints 'Hello' and 'Count of directory 0' and then everything inside countDir is printed.

Is the call to `countDir()` asynchronous? If so, how can I ensure that my calling code proceeds once `countDir()` has returned a result.

Comment: The second param of resolveLocalFileSystemURL (onSuccess) is async. The best way to handle this is to broadcast (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19446975/2608451) an event to your controller from inside the onSuccess body, so after the for loop inside the readEntries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous functions furnished to both `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and `reader.readEntries` are invoked asynchronously. The "AngularJS way" to handle this is to use the `$q` service to create and return a promise.

```
function countDirPromise(path){
  //create $q.defer object
  var q = $q.defer();
  var count = 0;
  console.log('Counting the files inside '+path);
  $window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function onUrlSuccess(fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function onReaderSuccess(entries) {
          var i;
          for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++)  {    
              console.log('File name ' + entries[i].name + ' added to count');
               count++;   
          }
          //resolve with count
          q.resolve(count);
        },
        function onReaderError(err) {             
          console.log(err);
          //reject with error
          q.reject(err);
        }
      );
    }, function onUrlError(err) {
      console.log(err);
      //reject with error
      q.reject(err);
    }
  );
  //return count promise
  return q.promise;
}
```

As you can see, there are four nested function: `onUrlSuccess`, `onUrlError`, `onReaderSuccess`, and `onReaderError`. Those functions get invoked asynchronously. The promise resolves with the value `count` if both `onUrlSuccess` and the nested function `onReaderSuccess` get invoked. The promise is rejected with an error if either the `onUrlError` function or `onReaderError` function get invoked.

### Usage

```
var countPromise = countDirPromise(cordova.file.dataDirectory +'/Images/');
console.log('Hello ');
countPromise.then(function onSuccess(count) {
    console.log('Count of directory '+count);
    //return to chain data
    return count;
}).catch(function onReject(err) {
    console.log(err);
    //throw to chain rejection
    throw err;
}).then(anotherSuccessFn, anotherRejectFn);
```

The functions furnished to both the `.then` and `.catch` methods are invoked asynchronously by the `$q` service.

For more information, see [AngularJS `$q` Service API Reference -- The Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)

---

### Using ngCordova

The alternative approach is to use the `$q` service promises returned by the [ngCordova $cordovaFile API](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

```
function countDirPromise(path){
  var count = 0;
  console.log('Counting the files inside '+path);
  var promise = $cordovaFile.checkDir(path);
  var derivedPromise = promise.then(
    function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
      var q = $q.defer()
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function onReaderSuccess(entries) {
          var i;
          for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++)  {    
              console.log('File name ' + entries[i].name + ' added to count');
               count++;   
          }
          //resolve with count
          q.resolve(count);
        },
        function onReaderError(err) {             
          console.log(err);
          //reject with error
          q.reject(err);
        }
      );
      //return to chain promise
      return q.promise;
    };
  });
  return derivedPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the .resolveLocalFileSystemUrl is async; you could tackle your issue using $q promise:

```
function countDir(path){
          var deff = $q.defer();
          var count = 0;
          console.log('Counting the files inside '+path);
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
            function (fileSystem) {
              var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
              reader.readEntries(
                function (entries) {
                  var i;
                  for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++)  {    
                      console.log('File name ' + entries[i].name + ' added to count');
                       count++;   
                  }

                 deff.resolve(count);
                },
                function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  deff.reject(err);
                }
              );
            }, function (err) {
              console.log(err);
              deff.reject(err);
            }
          );
  return deff.promise; 
}
```

And consume it as:

```
var count =0 ;
countDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory +'/Images/')
       .then( function(result){ count = result},
              function(err){ //handle error }
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass callback to countDir function and call it after the for loop.

```
 var count = countDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory +'/Images/', function(count){
   console.log('Hello ');
   console.log('Count of directory '+count);
});
```

And in the definition of the function.

```
function countDir(path, callback){
  ...
     for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++)  { 
       ... 
    }
    callback(count);
  ...
}
```