# How to call a sibling scope in angular js using rootscope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my app.js

```
  var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  app.controller("myFirstController",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.test = "myfirstName";
    $scope.test1 = "myfirstName";
  }])

  app.controller("mySecondController",['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.test = "myLastName";
    //Here how to call my test,test1 scope using $rootScope ?? 
  }])
```

Can i do this using $rootScope?I dont want to use any `emit` and `broadcast` or `this`

Comment: Inspect scope hierarchy, it's trivial to figure out how to do it. However, you should not do it, it's bad approach to access data like this.

Comment: Ya i checked my hirerarchy i am not seeing any my test and test1 variable... Ya ohk even though its a bad practise is it possible???

Comment: Controller should not even try to access data outside of its scope. If you don't care about app being low quality mess which hard to maintain then what you are trying to do it fine.

Comment: Use a service that's injected into both controllers. Services and factories are singletons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Comment: The best approach to do this **is not** with `$rootScope`. Are you sure you want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you store any value in rootscope like :

```
$rootScope.test =" value ";
```

and you can retrieve value from the rootScope  like

```
var value = $rootScope.test;
```

**But it's not good to use for data maintenance and security**

> because if you refresh browser, then all scope values are cleared.

So I will suggest you for 3 varies ways

- [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)
- [$ngStorage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)
- [$Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)
- [Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular)

> I dont want to use any emit and broadcast or

But that's the only way is best to [pass value from one controller to another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Comment: Worst practice approach possible.

Comment: @dfsq . Please read my full answer. and thanks for your comments :+1

Comment: Not only you are answering something else (it has nothing to do with data persistence, so storage, cookie is irrelevant) but you (as well as other answer) promote super low-quality design. You have controller what manages its state/data (`$scope`). Then all of a sudden this data gets changes by ... who know what (another controller). You see the problem here? That's why you should never mess with global values (`$rootScope`).

Comment: @dfsq . We never did it like angular.copy(), we just use `=`  assignment with the rootScope. So it's not affect.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? I explained why what you posted is really-really bad. How is it about `angular.copy`.. Whatever.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like below but use different names for avoiding errors in some cases.if you doesn't declare it as $rootScope in first ctrl then it will be undef in second ctrl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div ng-controller="myFirstController">
    
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="mySecondController">
    
    </div>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

 app.controller("myFirstController",['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.test = "myfirstName";
  }])

  app.controller("mySecondController",['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.test = "myLastName";
    console.log($rootScope.test);
    //Here how to call my myFirstName scope using $rootScope ?? 
  }])
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Worst practice approach possible.

Comment: why my $rootScope.test giving 'myLastName' ? in my rootscope there are two variable test i think? whats going on because  $rootScope.test = "myfirstName"; and  $scope.test = "myLastName"; are both child of my rootscope??

Comment: if you try like i said you wont get lastname....can u show how your trying