# How can we use controllers to share data between two different controllers in different HTML files in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have been using angularjs for developing web applications.
I want to add the data filled in chatCtrl(controller) in chat.html to another controller (chatScrnCtrl) in chatScrn.html, i.r both the html are different through ng-view. I hope you get what im saying, im designing a web messenger application and i need to add the chat to the chatscreen once i type in the chatlist. I also need to display these in the chat history page. Hope u guys understand what i need. so pls provide a way for this rather than providing me the solution to access controllers in the same html file or the same js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: pls read my edited question and give a solution.

Comment: the solution u gave is just for the input data to be displayed in another text using ng-model and controller. i know the basics and im not that dumb to ask such a question

Comment: Use custom service..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try to utilize services provided by angularjs, use [$broadcast to tranfer data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a angular service with `Getters()` and `Setters()` method and inject them in your controller.